# "Opendaylight": Integration with openstack with opendaylight issue

Tags: opendaylight, tripleo

I am installing opendaylight in existing openstack environment and I am facing issue in the same. Please find the details below.

## Openstack environment:

1. I have 1 Controller node with neutron service and ML2 service enabled.
2. I have 1 Compute node with neutron services, OVS service, DHCP service and metadat service enabled.
3. One Management network and one external network.
   The system is working fine with OVS configuration. below operation is performed successfully.

   - Can create provider network.
   - Can create selfservice network.
   - Can create router and attach the selfservice and provider network for north-south traffic.
   - Can create Instance and access the same with internal IP. Internet is accessible in instance.
   - Can assign floating IP from provider network.

Issue in installing Opendaylight
I have downloaded the Opendaylight BOron source "distribution-karaf-0.5.1-Boron-SR1.tar.gz"
`- Untar to distribution-karaf-0.5.1-Boron-SR1`

```
[root@Controller distribution-karaf-0.5.1-Boron-SR1]# ./bin/start
[root@Controller distribution-karaf-0.5.1-Boron-SR1]# ./bin/client
```

`client: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
Logging in as karaf
982 [sshd-SshClient[1c6b6478]-nio2-thread-3] WARN org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier - Server at [/0.0.0.0:8101, RSA, 97:9e:91:2d:27:e1:49:c5:cb:b4:22:e8:18:52:1f:a6] presented unverified {} key: {}`

```
________                       ________                .__  .__       .__     __
\_____  \ ______   ____   ____ \______ \ _____  ___.__.|  | |__| ____ |  |___/  |_
 /   |   \\____ \_/ __ \ /    \ |    |  \\__  \<   |  ||  | |  |/ ___\|  |  \   __\
/    |    \  |_> >  ___/|   |  \|    `   \/ __ \\___  ||  |_|  / /_/  >   Y  \  |
\_______  /   __/ \___  >___|  /_______  (____  / ____||____/__\___  /|___|  /__|
        \/|__|        \/     \/        \/     \/\/            /_____/      \/
```

`Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown OpenDaylight.`

```
[root@Controller distribution-karaf-0.5.1-Boron-SR1]# feature:install odl-ovsdb-openstack odl-dlux-core

[root@Controller distribution-karaf-0.5.1-Boron-SR1]# feature:install odl-dlux-all odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch`
```

Once I hit the url "http://127.0.0.1:8181/dlux/index.html" or "http://127.0.0.1:8181/index.html" it is not loading the output. Opendaylight login page not showing.

Kindly suggest what could be done here or I am missing some thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use existing deployment tools vs duplicating them yourself.

Take a look at [OPNFV's Apex installer project](http://artifacts.opnfv.org/apex/docs/installation-instructions/). It will handle all of this for you. Apex is based on TripleO, which consumes OpenDaylight via [puppet-opendaylight](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/packaging/puppet-opendaylight.git;a=tree) and [upstream ODL RPM packages](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/submodules/integration/packaging/docs/packages.html). It's quite mature and feature rich.

Note that OpenDaylight Boron is deprecated.